# Spearman Correlation on timeseries acquired at different resolutions in R

Tags: r, time-series, interpolation, correlation

I am working in R, and I have got these two timeseries:

```
structure(list(Date_SAR = c("10/05/2003", "14/06/2003", "19/07/2003",
"23/08/2003", "27/09/2003", "01/11/2003", "06/12/2003", "10/01/2004",
"14/02/2004", "20/03/2004", "24/04/2004", "29/05/2004", "03/07/2004",
"07/08/2004", "11/09/2004", "16/10/2004", "20/11/2004", "25/12/2004",
"29/01/2005", "05/03/2005", "09/04/2005", "14/05/2005", "18/06/2005",
"23/07/2005", "27/08/2005", "01/10/2005", "05/11/2005", "10/12/2005",
"14/01/2006", "18/02/2006", "25/03/2006", "29/04/2006", "03/06/2006",
"08/07/2006", "12/08/2006", "16/09/2006", "21/10/2006"), SAR = c(11,
9.175, 5.525, 1.875, -9.67, -18.3383, -16.235, -14.1317, -12.7163,
-11.9888, -11.2613, -10.5338, -7.97, -10.1583, -18.935, -27.7117,
-19.755, -8.98, 2.38, 5.1575, -15.1475, -24.5767, -23.13, -21.6833,
-22.59, -23.71, -21.485, -9.45, -2.32, -12.825, -27.455, -30.02,
-37.04, -44.0075, -34.4025, -27.3975, -22.9925)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-37L))
```

and

```
structure(list(Date_GWL = c("15/02/2003", "15/03/2003", "15/04/2003",
"15/05/2003", "15/06/2003", "15/07/2003", "15/08/2003", "15/09/2003",
"15/10/2003", "15/11/2003", "15/12/2003", "15/01/2004", "15/02/2004",
"15/03/2004", "15/04/2004", "15/05/2004", "15/06/2004", "15/07/2004",
"15/08/2004", "15/09/2004", "15/10/2004", "15/11/2004", "15/12/2004",
"15/01/2005", "15/02/2005", "15/03/2005", "15/04/2005", "15/05/2005",
"15/06/2005", "15/07/2005", "15/08/2005", "15/09/2005", "15/10/2005",
"15/11/2005", "15/12/2005", "15/01/2006", "15/02/2006", "15/03/2006",
"15/04/2006", "15/05/2006", "15/06/2006", "15/07/2006", "15/08/2006",
"15/09/2006", "15/10/2006", "15/11/2006", "15/12/2006", "15/01/2007"
), GWL = c(-173.41, -174.23, -175.06, -175.77, -176.2, -176.56,
-177.2, -177.7, -178.06, -177.94, -178.15, -178.7, -179, -179.15,
-179.51, -179.32, -179.14, -179.8, -180.2, -180.87, -180.4, -179.5,
-178.06, -179.38, -180.71, -180.3, -179.19, -178.09, -178.82,
-179.55, -180.28, -181.01, -179.67, -178.34, -178.1, -177.9,
-177.71, -177.77, -177.83, -178.5, -179.5, -180.5, -181.63, -181.24,
-180.86, -180.11, -179.37, -178.62)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-48L))
```

As you can see, these two time series are for the same timeframe (2003-2007) but have been acquired at different resolutions. I would like to perform a simple Spearman correlation, but I don't really know how to do it. I was thinking about some interpolation to let the data points match somehow, but unfortunately, I am not able to do this by myself.
Would you be able to help me out with this matter?

Comment: A simple plot of the series suggest that they are not stationary. You should not estimate a correlation coefficient between these two series as that will lead you to potentially misleading results. There are many posts on this site discussing this exact issue, you should have a look https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=time+series+correlation and https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=time+series+correlation+nonstationary.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea

- what these variables are (and hence on whether one is a response, and so forth)
- how far each series is exact for or known at the daily dates specified (in particular,   `GWL` looks like monthly levels, with just a conventional publication or reference date of day 15 in each month)
- how to approach this in R, but on CV statistical answers are expected. I used Stata.

On the face of it interpolation could be indulged and most of the structure in the data comes from the first year or so of data, although it's exaggerated by extrapolation, which is as usual is probably a bad idea.

The plots show the original data, each series interpolated and extrapolated linearly and a scatter plot for the data in common, with join in time order.

I don't hold out much hope that a Spearman correlation would be helpful, but it is possible after interpolation.

I haven't tried to look at e.g. cross-correlation, let alone what kind of model could make sense here.

[image]

[image]